# Using savePCDFileASCII, PCD file isn't created (no errors though)

Tags: pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'm using an XV-11 and IMU to create a 3D sensor_msgs::PointCloud which is successfully advertised on a topic. I want to convert that cloud into a sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 and then pcl::PointCloud. I would also like to convert the intensities into RGB values, but I was having too many problems accessing/editing the rgb values for pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB. So, I ended up with this code for just the XYZ values...

```
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud_out;
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud2_out;
```

... calculations and unnecessary code omitted

```
    sensor_msgs::convertPointCloudToPointCloud2 (cloud_out, cloud2_out);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> pcl_cloud;
    pcl::fromROSMsg(cloud2_out, pcl_cloud);
    pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("test_pcd123.pcd", pcl_cloud);
```

which compiles and runs without any errors, except that test_pcd123.pcd cannot be found anywhere on my computer. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

When I use `std::cerr << "Saved " << pcl_cloud.points.size () << " data points to test_pcd.pcd." << std::endl;`, a correct message of `Saved 360 data points to test_pcd.pcd.` is shown

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239842/using-savepcdfileascii,-pcd-file-isn%27t-created-(no-errors-though)/) by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Made a minor change, now it works

```
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> pcl_cloud;
    pcl::fromROSMsg(cloud2_out, pcl_cloud);

    writeCount++;
    char filename[100];
    sprintf(filename, "/home/ateator/catkin_ws/src/laser_assembler/src/outputpcd/output%dx.pcd", writeCount);

    pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII (filename, pcl_cloud);
```

---

Originally posted by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) with karma: 37 on 2016-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0